# Importing data from SQL Server to HIVE using SQOOP

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am able to successfully import data from SQL Server to HDFS using sqoop. However, when it tries to link to HIVE I get an error. I am not sure I understand the error correctly

```
sudo -u hdfs sqoop import  \
-Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true  \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://XX.XX.X.X:1433;instanceName=data-engr-sql-svr;  databaseName=AdventureWorks2019"  \
--username sa  \
--password XXXXXXXX  \
--driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver  \
--warehouse-dir "/user/hive/warehouse/AdventureWorks2019.db"  \
--hive-import  \
--create-hive-table  \
--fields-terminated-by ',' \
--hive-table AdventureWorks2019.Production.TransactionHistory  \
--table Production.TransactionHistory  \
--split-by TransactionID  \
-- --schema Production
```

I don't know how to handle schemas, most of the tutorial uses a dummy database without proper schemas which are not helpful.

Error

> 21/03/31 08:52:47 INFO conf.HiveConf: Using the default value passed in for log id: 95e2b831-cfe5-4108-be0f-0df1d9a8797e
> 21/03/31 08:52:47 INFO session.SessionState: Updating thread name to 95e2b831-cfe5-4108-be0f-0df1d9a8797e main
> 21/03/31 08:52:47 INFO conf.HiveConf: Using the default value passed in for log id: 95e2b831-cfe5-4108-be0f-0df1d9a8797e
> 21/03/31 08:52:47 INFO ql.Driver: Compiling command(queryId=hdfs_20210331085247_050638e8-593a-4d01-8020-c40b7db8e66a): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AdventureWorks2019.Production.TransactionHistory` ( `TransactionID` INT, `ProductID` INT, `ReferenceOrderID` INT, `ReferenceOrderLineID` INT, `TransactionDate` STRING, `TransactionType` STRING, `Quantity` INT, `ActualCost` DOUBLE, `ModifiedDate` STRING) COMMENT 'Imported by sqoop on 2021/03/31 08:52:45' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\054' LINES TERMINATED BY '\012' STORED AS TEXTFILE
> 21/03/31 08:52:49 INFO hive.metastore: HMS client filtering is enabled.
> 21/03/31 08:52:49 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://cnt7-naya-cdh63:9083
> 21/03/31 08:52:49 INFO hive.metastore: Opened a connection to metastore, current connections: 1
> 21/03/31 08:52:49 INFO hive.metastore: Connected to metastore.
> 21/03/31 08:52:49 INFO parse.SemanticAnalyzer: Starting Semantic Analysis
> **FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10255]: Invalid table name AdventureWorks2019.Production.TransactionHistory
> 21/03/31 08:52:49 ERROR ql.Driver: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10255]: Invalid table name AdventureWorks2019.Production.TransactionHistory**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as schema inside the database in Hive. `Database` and `schema` mean the same thing and can be used interchangeably.

So, the bug is in using `database.schema.table`. Use `database.table` in Hive.

Read the documentation: [Create/Drop/Alter/UseDatabase](http://%20https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/Alter/UseDatabase)